# hiding inner tables with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to hide an inner table with JQuery where the  element that triggers the hiding is in the parent table. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".collapsible").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        inner = $(this).find(".inner");



        if($(inner).is(":visible") == true) {

            alert("hiding");

            $(inner).hide("slow");

        }

        else {

            alert("showing");

            $(inner).show("slow");

        }

    });

    $(".inner").each(function(index, element) {

        $(this).hide(0);

    });
});
</script>

<table class='outer'>
<tr><td><a class='collapsible' href='#'>click here</a></td></tr>
<tr><table class='inner'>
<tr><td>thing</td></tr><tr><td>another thing</td></tr>
</table>
</table>
<table class='outer'>
<tr><td><a class='collapsible' href='#'>click here</a></td></tr>
<tr><table class='inner'>
<tr><td>something else</td></tr><tr><td>another something else</td></tr>
</table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know why clicking on "click here" not make the inner table show? Thanks in advance

Comment: Merged your accounts; please consider registering!

Answer (score 0):

Because `.find()` is looking within the `.collapsible` anchor. You need to step up to the parent table first to use `.find()` correctly:

```
$(this).closest("table.outer").find("table.inner");
```

Your whole code can be simplified to:

```
$(function() {
    $(".collapsible").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("table.outer").find("table.inner").toggle('slow');
    });

    $(".inner").hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the table to show with the additions to my code. I wrote another method for trying to toggle the hidden inner tables but it also isn't working.

Comment: @GotSomeQuestions - another problem is that the inner table needs to be within a `<td>` as well. Also see my updated code.